# How do I capture an SQL output parameter in C# of type 'table'?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) Kitten 
SET Owner = 'Brian' 
OUTPUT inserted.KittenId INTO @result
```

`@result` is type 'table'.

In C# I would capture an `OUTPUT` parameter I believe with this code:

```
var resultParameter = new SqlParameter("result", SqlDbType.Int);
resultParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

However that code is an `SqlDbType.Int` and there is no `table` type.

Any ideas? An alternative would be to somehow cast the table in the SQL query to an integer, as it will always return a single integer value or `NULL`.

Comment: But storing the result into a variable is not the same as an output parameter

Comment: I'm just guessing - perhaps `SqlDbType.Structured` ?

Comment: And you actually only output an id - `KittenId`

Comment: `Structured` looks like it might be along the right lines, I am getting `The table type parameter 'result' must have a valid type name.` though which is something else I think involving registering a type.

Comment: `result` isn't an INT because technically the UPDATE could return multiple values if it updates multiple rows, so it ends up being a table variable with a single value in due to the `top (1)`

Comment: I think.`Structured` but with input parameters you have to specify the type name of the structured parameter and that has to match a user defined type in SQL, not sure what it requires with output parameters.. Can you not `select from @result` instead of doing a `return`?

Comment: @SLC ah I see. it's probably because `SqlDbType.Structured` needs a created table value type. Maybe try to create one with just single int column and then try again.

Comment: @SLC `SqlParameter outputParam = new SqlParameter(); 
    outputParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
    outputParam .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: It's moot anyway, it seems that table parameters don't support OUTPUT direction...

Comment: @Slc reference: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13782/table-valued-parameter-as-output-parameter-for-stored-procedure

Comment: @SLC still you can do a SELECT * FROM @ result and return the result as the result of the stored procedure/command, as suggested by pinkfloydx